# Touchpad from HP laptop not working on OpenBSD

Tags: openbsd, touchpad

I have installed OpenBSD 6.8 on a HP laptop. I have also installed xfce4.
My problem is that the touchpad of the laptop does not work.
Running the following command:  `dmesg | grep Touchpad` the system prints pms0: Elantech Touchpad, version 4, firmware 0x5d4f01.
Is there a way to configure the system in order to have the touchpad working properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try `doas wsconsctl mouse.tp.tapping=1`